# Kernel compile errors

Tags: compiling

Years later i turn back to ubuntu 20.04 and trying to compile android kernel but strangely terminal giving some strange errors like

```
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:18:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:19:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:20:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:21:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:21:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:24:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:24:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:24:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:24:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
drivers/sensorhub/brcm/bbdpl/Kconfig:24:warning: ignoring unsupported character '
```

This file looking like this;

```
choice
    depends on SENSORS_SSP_BBD
    prompt "Choose serial connection with chip"
    default BCM_GPS_SPI_DRIVER

config BCM_GPS_TTY_DRIVER
    bool  "TTY"
    depends on TTY
    help
        Support for BRCM GPS UART driver.

config BCM_GPS_I2C_DRIVER
    bool "I2C"
    depends on I2C
    help
        Support for BRCM GPS I2C driver.

config BCM_GPS_SPI_DRIVER
    bool "SPI"
    depends on SPI
    help
        Support for BRCM GPS SPI driver.

endchoice
```

It seems to me causing from ubuntu. Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Did the file come from a system that put `^M` at end of  line?

Comment: Is it successfully compiling? Warnings just warn of things that usually aren't blocking. In this case, some unsupported character is being ignored; it shouldn't be causing any issues that would prevent it from compiling.